# CUDA kernel function taking longer than equivalent host function

Tags: c, cuda, gpgpu

I'm following along with http://code.google.com/p/stanford-cs193g-sp2010/ and the video lectures posted online, doing one of the problem sets posted (the first one) I've encountered something slightly counterintuitive at least with respect to the way the question is asked. The question asks me to derive a timing model for execution time on the cpu and gpu assuming linear scaling based on timings from a sample application run on my own machine.

> -Plug the timing numbers printed by the code on the computer you're
>   working  on into that equation and report what the break even point 
>   (when the cpu version is as fast as the gpu version) will be.

The issue I'm having is that my kernel is taking a lot longer than the host version of the equivalent function (I'll post both below), such that there is no break even point. The numbers I'm getting are as follows.

```
done with copy to gpu kernel
copy to gpu took 26.30630 ms
done with gpu shift cypher kernel
gpu shift cypher took 7.33203 ms
done with copy from gpu kernel
copy from gpu took 28.54141 ms
host shift cypher took 0.00186 ms
Worked! CUDA and reference output match.
```

Do you think there is something wrong with the way I'm doing things? Here is the kernel and host functions.

```
// This kernel implements a per element shift
__global__ void shift_cypher(unsigned int *input_array, unsigned int *output_array, 
    unsigned int shift_amount, unsigned int alphabet_max, unsigned int array_length)
{
    int gid = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    output_array[gid] = (input_array[gid] + shift_amount)%(alphabet_max+1);
}

void host_shift_cypher(unsigned int *input_array, unsigned int *output_array, unsigned int shift_amount, unsigned int alphabet_max, unsigned int array_length)
{
  for(unsigned int i=0;i<array_length;i++)
  {
    int element = input_array[i];
    int shifted = element + shift_amount;
    if(shifted > alphabet_max)
    {
      shifted = shifted % (alphabet_max + 1);
    }
    output_array[i] = shifted;
  }
}
```

The sample application runs with 16MB of integer elements, with a block size of 512. Here is the full source for the file in question http://pastebin.com/htYH0bA2

Comment: What kind of CPU and GPU are you using for testing? The assignments from the Stanford class assumed hardware similar to what students were supplied with in their lab resources (discrete gaming GPUs, basically). For your hardware, there may be no break even point if you have a somewhat anemic GPU (many laptop models, for example).  Do you know how many SMs are in the GPU you're testing?

Comment: I have a GT430 (this one to be exact http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814162067) the CPU is an AMD Phenom II X4 (3.4Ghz). Wikipedia says the GPU has 2 streaming multiprocessors. Does the host performance run time look  typical to you? It seems extremely short.

Comment: Here is my result on a ~3 year old laptop: ```host shift cypher took 280.5 ms```.  So, the timing of the host version does seem to be way off.

Comment: I just added a sleep function that sleeps for 1000ms and it is being reported as 0.00173ms when using start_timer/stop_timer. You can see the program stopping for 1 second. I should have mentioned in the original post I am on windows, perhaps there is a difference in the way it handles synchronization and the stop_timer is getting called before the host function completes. I will try to set it up on my ubuntu partition and see what kind of results I get.

Comment: I didn't have to set it up on my ubuntu partition, I fixed it by adding a cudaThreadSynchronize to the start_timer. I now get ~150ms for the host code and 1000ms for the 1 seconds sleep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> host shift cypher took 0.00186 ms

This looks very odd. Whatever you do with 16MB on a CPU, it should take more than a fraction of a millisecond.

By looking at the pastebin code it seems you time everything with CUDA events. Although I have not used them, my guess is that you measure actual time of GPU Kernels executing with this. Which, in the case of just calling host code will be next to nothing. Is this really how they measure host code executing in the Stanford course?

You could prove me wrong by just checking this result with any kind of C timer.

Comment: yes they provide everything except cuda kernel which you are supposed to write as a basic exercise, I wonder if the timers function differently on unix/windows machines, I will swap out the timer functions for the host code and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

This was a problem with the timer as w.m pointed out. The issue was, I believe, that the event recording functions in the timer handed off control to the cpu based host function before recording the event. It's sort of confusing because you would think that recording the event would occur within the time the host code is executing but it seems that it was doing something more like recording the start and stop events simultaneously, both after the host code finished executing. Adding a `cudaThreadSynchronize();` to the start timer seems to fix the problem (ensuring the event gets recorded before continuing with the host code. This could be a windows only discrepancy or based on my CUDA version or hardware etc I'm not sure. In any case my new, much more normal results are as follows.

```
done with copy to gpu kernel
copy to gpu took 25.75683 ms
done with gpu shift cypher kernel
gpu shift cypher took 7.45667 ms
done with copy from gpu kernel
copy from gpu took 29.10922 ms
host shift cypher took 153.98772 ms
1 second sleep took 999.85291 ms
Worked! CUDA and reference output match.
```

Comment: Yes, I believe that's the problem with the windows, cudaEvent_t works fine in *nix system, I think clock_t timing or QueryPerformanceCounter/QueryPerformanceFrequency should be a better choice in windows.